# Trouble with sending a left click

Tags: vba, excel, mouse

I have a series of clicks and cursor movements I have in a macro. Everything works fine until the end. All the clicks work until the last click. I have tried to put various amounts of sleeps in between the clicks and before the clicks.

Whats odd is that when i click for real it works! ahh
Whats also odd is if i press enter it works BUTTTT! SendKeys "{ENTER}" will not press the button

This is my code:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
'Declare mouse events

Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
'Declare sleep
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)



Private Sub AAA()
    Sleep 150
SetCursorPos 80, 80 'x and y position
 mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
 Sleep 50
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0



    Sleep 150
SetCursorPos 80, 170 'x and y position
 mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
 Sleep 50
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

Sleep 10
SetCursorPos 85, 270 'x and y position
 mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
 Sleep 10
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

    Sleep 10
SetCursorPos 340, 170 'x and y position
 mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
 Sleep 10
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

Sleep 10
SetCursorPos 300, 475 'x and y position
 mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0




End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to click? As in what application? There may be a better way, using a specific library to interact with that application. I know I started where you are when looking at IE Automation, but then quickly moved to HTML parsing and getelementbyid tasks, as the mouse position was too volatile for an enduring solution (change screen resolution, zoom factors etc).

Comment: Seconded @Sercho . SendKeys or sending mouse clicks is unreliable. If your second to last mouse_event causes a change in focus, the last mouse_event might not "click" where you want it to and hence "not work".